# Skipping whitespaces when reading file python

Tags: python, readfile, removing-whitespace

Im working on a very long project where I read from a file saved in my campus network system, When reading the file, everything works perfectly IF i delete the white spaces at the bottom of the list, but when i leave them in(like the prof wants) i get an error, "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Date'"
Ive tried a few different options to ignore white spaces but none have worked-
 List of what Ive tried

```
 with open("C:\\Users\\Brayd\OneDrive\\Documents\\2015HomicideLog_FINAL.txt") as f_in:
     lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f_in) 
     lines = list(line for line in lines if line)

for line in file: if not line.strip(): print("it is empty line")

with open("fname.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
      if not line.strip():
         file.close()


with open file as f_in: lines = list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f_in) if line)
```

Nothing has worked, Here is what i use when deleting white spaces in file and it works perfectly

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\Brayd\OneDrive\\Documents\\2015HomicideLog_FINAL.txt" , "r")
lines=file.readlines()[1:]
file.close()
```

I've been working and trying to get it to work around the whitespaces for 12 hours now and haven't had any luck... Any ideas guys?

Here is what text file looks like-

```
Date   Event #  TIME    Victim Name     V R/G   V Age
150101 0685 2:03    Anderson, Kedral    BM  26
150103 0816 5:57    Shines, Kathryn     WF  54
150106 4417 22:06   Norton, Noella      HF  46
150107 4655 23:27   Speidel, Steven     WM  41
150110 1100 8:35    Orozco, Jose        HM  53
*blank spaces here*
     *blank spaces here*
*BSH^*
```

For a better example of what my program does, here is the full code

```
def dayofmurder(date): #function to find day of the murder
    date = date%10000 #takes 10000 out leaving 2 digits for year
    month = date//100 #takes 100 out leaving 1-2 digits for month
    date= date %100 # mod 100 to figure out date
    day=date #day=date
    monthlist = [0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334] #possible months through date ranges
    daysofweek = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", #list of days of the week
    "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
    startonday = 4 #start on 4th day (thursday) per txt file
    startonday = monthlist[month-1]+(day-1)+startonday # start on day w/ days
    startonday %= 7 #mod 7 to find day of week
    return daysofweek[startonday] #return the day of the week homicide was on

daysoftheweek = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
"Thursday","Friday","Saturday"] #list of days of the week for printing in order


file = open("C:\\Users\\Brayd\OneDrive\\Documents\\2015HomicideLog_FINAL.txt" , "r")
lines=file.readlines()[1:]
file.close()

print("Days Homicides Happened on:")
dayOfmurders = {"Sunday": 0 ,"Monday": 0,"Tuesday": 0,"Wednesday": 0,
"Thursday":0, "Friday": 0,"Saturday": 0} #list of days and start vaule of 0 
#murders
for line in lines: #reads all lines
    value=line.split() #splits each value in line
    listdays=(dayofmurder(int(value[0]))) #for every value in the row
    dayOfmurders[listdays] = dayOfmurders[listdays] + 1 #every time there is an
    #occurance, add 1 to total value in dayOfmurders

for v in daysoftheweek: #in order of value (S-M-T-W-TH-F-S (from daysoftheweek 
    print(dayOfmurders[v],"homicides happen on a", v)   #prints [v](value) of 
    #daysOfmurders with string " " and prints v (value) in daysoftheweek)
print("----------------------------------",'\n', "Number of Homicides\
in hour block:")
time = {"0:" : 0, "1:" : 0, "2:" : 0, "3:" : 0, "4:" : 0, "5:" : 0, "6:" : 0,
        ##list of possible time's
        "7:" : 0,"8:" : 0, "9:" : 0, "10" : 0, "11" : 0,"12" : 0, "13" : 0,   
        # " " is the hour possible
        "14" : 0, "15" : 0,"16" : 0,  "17" : 0, "18" : 0, "19" : 0,"20" : 0,  
        # 0 value is the number of occurances
        "21" : 0, "22" : 0, "23" : 0}
for line in lines:      #reads each line of the file
    value=line.split()  #splits up each value in the line
    listdays=(value[2][0:2])  #moves the index of the line and grabs only 
    #first 2 variables
    time[listdays] = time[listdays] + 1

for k,v in time.items():  #uses key and value in time dict
    print(v,"Homicides happened in",k,"hour block")  #
print("----------------------------------",'\n', "Races and Occurances of Hom\
idices")
races = {"HF": 0 ,"HM": 0,"WF": 0,"WM": 0,"AF":0, "BM": 0,"BF": 0, "AM": 0} 
#list of races and start value of 0
for line in lines: #function to find all races in Homicide File
    value=line.split()
    listdays=(value[5])
    if listdays == "Chunng": #if statement for the people who have more than2 
    #names
        listdays = (value[6]) #if they do have more than 2 names, move to the 
        #next index slot and to register race
    elif listdays == "Terrance": #same as above
        listdays = (value[6]) #same as above
    elif listdays == "Lasunda": #same as above
        listdays = (value[6]) #same as above
    else:
        listdays = (value[5]) #same as above
    races[listdays] = races[listdays] + 1 #for every occurance add's 1 to the
    #value

for k,v in races.items(): #uses key and value in dictionary races
    print(k,"=",v) #prints key and value in race dictionary

ages = { "0" : 0, "1" : 0, "2" : 0, "3" : 0, #list of all possible ages and
# their
        "4" : 0, "5" : 0, "6" : 0,"7" : 0,  #occurances
        "8" : 0,"9" : 0}

for line in lines:   #function to find all ages in Homicide File
    value = line.split()
    listdays = (value[6][0])
    if listdays == "A": #for people w/ 3 names, if index 6 = a/b/t(see race's)
        listdays = (value[7][0]) # skip to next index and use index 7
    elif listdays == "B":
        listdays = (value[7][0])
    elif listdays == "T":
        listdays = (value[7][0])
    else:
        listdays = (value[6][0])
    ages[listdays] = ages[listdays]+ 1 #adds all occurances

for k,v in ages.items(): #uses key and value in dictionary ages
    print(k, "=", v) #prints key and value in age dictionary

print("----------------------------------",'\n', "Here are the Graphs from\
data found above")

import pylab #importing pylab for graphs
bar_width = .75
x_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] #range 1-7
y_values = [13,25,17,26,20,14,19] # data from murder occurances, see above
tlabel = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
pylab.title("Homicide Occurenece by Day of Week Per Homicides File")
pylab.bar(x_values, y_values, width=bar_width, tick_label = tlabel, align = 
'center' , color = 'b')
pylab.show()

pylab.axes(aspect = 1) #used pylab example from sheet
values = [39, 11, 31, 6, 1, 2, 29, 15] #data from race/gender see above
pie_labels = ["BM", "BF", "HM", "HF", "AM", "AF", "WM", "WF"]
color_list = ['purple', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'red',
              'white']
pylab.pie(values,autopct = '%1.f%%', labels = pie_labels, colors=color_list)
pylab.title("Pie Chart Showing Racial and Gender Breakdown in Homicides File")
pylab.show()    


bar_width = .5 #used pylab examples from sheet (sets bar width)
x_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #range 0-9 (0-9,10-19,20-29... ect)
y_values = [4,7,27,41,4,15,7,6,2,5] # number of occurances per age
tlabel = ["0-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60",
          "61-70", "71-80", "81-90", "90+"]
pylab.title("Homicides per Age Categories in Homocide File")
pylab.bar(x_values, y_values, width=bar_width, tick_label = tlabel, align = 
'center' , color = 'b')
pylab.show()

bar_width = .3 #pylab example from sheet(sets bar width)
x_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
#^number of hours possible for murders
y_values = [3,3,7,1,4,6,4,4,4,5,5,3,8,4,6,2,5,13,10,6,7,5,13,6] #occurances
#of deaths per hour
tlabel = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",
          "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"]
pylab.title("Homicides Per Hour of the Clock in Homicide File")
pylab.bar(x_values, y_values, width=bar_width, tick_label = tlabel, align =
 'center' , color = 'b')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: try with yourstring.replace(" ", "")

Comment: What do you mean? Where do I put that? @eyllanesc

Comment: `... do something` is the part which is throwing error, and you have not shared that content. Based on what you shared, you are doing `if not line.strip()`, but it doesn't actually remove the white space content from the string

Comment: I don't leave the ...do something in the program, I replace it with file.close() @MoinuddinQuadri

Comment: what do you mean with at the end of program? small example of txt file would be helpful

Comment: I don't understand your statement in the code `lines=file.readlines()[1:]`, because this my friend dosen't "delete" white spaces, but just copy the whole file to a list, line by line, starting from the second line.

Comment: @Mixone I put a small example of the txt file in the question I hope it helps, sorry for late response had a class to go to

Comment: @Nf4r the reason i have `lines=file.readlines()[1:]` is because of the header in the txt file, see edited question for txt file example

Comment: @BraydenHark two things: 1) Is there any indication before the whitespace? 2) Is it spaces or just a new line?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some debugging tips. These are very helpful when your code doesn't work quite the way you want it to.

Comment: Also, will you create a [mcve] as a separate python script and [edit] your question to include it? This will greatly help you focus on the specifics of the problem you are trying to solve without all the noise from unrelated complexities of your full project.

Answer (score 0):

To skip empty lines and spaces at the ends of line you can do

```
lines = []
with open("fname.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)

# do something with lines         
print(lines[1:])

print("Days Homicides Happened on:")
```

or shorter

```
with open("fname.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]

# do something with lines         
print(lines[1:])         

print("Days Homicides Happened on:")
```

or read normally and check every line in code before you do shomething

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\Brayd\OneDrive\\Documents\\2015HomicideLog_FINAL.txt" , "r")
lines = file.readlines()[1:]
file.close()

print("Days Homicides Happened on:") 

for line in lines:
    # check if line is not empty
    if line.strip():
        # do something with not-empty line
        for number in line.split():
         print(int(number))
```

---

**EDIT:** full code which works for me

```
def dayofmurder(date): #function to find day of the murder
    date = date%10000 #takes 10000 out leaving 2 digits for year
    month = date//100 #takes 100 out leaving 1-2 digits for month
    date= date %100 # mod 100 to figure out date
    day=date #day=date
    monthlist = [0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334] #possible months through date ranges
    daysofweek = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", #list of days of the week
    "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
    startonday = 4 #start on 4th day (thursday) per txt file
    startonday = monthlist[month-1]+(day-1)+startonday # start on day w/ days
    startonday %= 7 #mod 7 to find day of week
    return daysofweek[startonday] #return the day of the week homicide was on

daysoftheweek = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
"Thursday","Friday","Saturday"] #list of days of the week for printing in order

#-------------------------

# OPEN FUNCTION THAT WORKS WITH ORYGINAL FILE

with open("fname.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]

# skip headers         
lines = lines[1:]

#-------------------------

print("Days Homicides Happened on:")
dayOfmurders = {"Sunday": 0 ,"Monday": 0,"Tuesday": 0,"Wednesday": 0,
"Thursday":0, "Friday": 0,"Saturday": 0} #list of days and start vaule of 0 
#murders
for line in lines: #reads all lines
    value=line.split() #splits each value in line
    listdays=(dayofmurder(int(value[0]))) #for every value in the row
    dayOfmurders[listdays] = dayOfmurders[listdays] + 1 #every time there is an
    #occurance, add 1 to total value in dayOfmurders

for v in daysoftheweek: #in order of value (S-M-T-W-TH-F-S (from daysoftheweek 
    print(dayOfmurders[v],"homicides happen on a", v)   #prints [v](value) of 
    #daysOfmurders with string " " and prints v (value) in daysoftheweek)
print("----------------------------------",'\n', "Number of Homicides\
in hour block:")
time = {"0:" : 0, "1:" : 0, "2:" : 0, "3:" : 0, "4:" : 0, "5:" : 0, "6:" : 0,
        ##list of possible time's
        "7:" : 0,"8:" : 0, "9:" : 0, "10" : 0, "11" : 0,"12" : 0, "13" : 0,   
        # " " is the hour possible
        "14" : 0, "15" : 0,"16" : 0,  "17" : 0, "18" : 0, "19" : 0,"20" : 0,  
        # 0 value is the number of occurances
        "21" : 0, "22" : 0, "23" : 0}
for line in lines:      #reads each line of the file
    value=line.split()  #splits up each value in the line
    listdays=(value[2][0:2])  #moves the index of the line and grabs only 
    #first 2 variables
    time[listdays] = time[listdays] + 1

for k,v in time.items():  #uses key and value in time dict
    print(v,"Homicides happened in",k,"hour block")  #
print("----------------------------------",'\n', "Races and Occurances of Hom\
idices")
races = {"HF": 0 ,"HM": 0,"WF": 0,"WM": 0,"AF":0, "BM": 0,"BF": 0, "AM": 0} 
#list of races and start value of 0
for line in lines: #function to find all races in Homicide File
    value=line.split()
    listdays=(value[5])
    if listdays == "Chunng": #if statement for the people who have more than2 
    #names
        listdays = (value[6]) #if they do have more than 2 names, move to the 
        #next index slot and to register race
    elif listdays == "Terrance": #same as above
        listdays = (value[6]) #same as above
    elif listdays == "Lasunda": #same as above
        listdays = (value[6]) #same as above
    else:
        listdays = (value[5]) #same as above
    races[listdays] = races[listdays] + 1 #for every occurance add's 1 to the
    #value

for k,v in races.items(): #uses key and value in dictionary races
    print(k,"=",v) #prints key and value in race dictionary

ages = { "0" : 0, "1" : 0, "2" : 0, "3" : 0, #list of all possible ages and
# their
        "4" : 0, "5" : 0, "6" : 0,"7" : 0,  #occurances
        "8" : 0,"9" : 0}

for line in lines:   #function to find all ages in Homicide File
    value = line.split()
    listdays = (value[6][0])
    if listdays == "A": #for people w/ 3 names, if index 6 = a/b/t(see race's)
        listdays = (value[7][0]) # skip to next index and use index 7
    elif listdays == "B":
        listdays = (value[7][0])
    elif listdays == "T":
        listdays = (value[7][0])
    else:
        listdays = (value[6][0])
    ages[listdays] = ages[listdays]+ 1 #adds all occurances

for k,v in ages.items(): #uses key and value in dictionary ages
    print(k, "=", v) #prints key and value in age dictionary

print("----------------------------------",'\n', "Here are the Graphs from\
data found above")

import pylab #importing pylab for graphs
bar_width = .75
x_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] #range 1-7
y_values = [13,25,17,26,20,14,19] # data from murder occurances, see above
tlabel = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
pylab.title("Homicide Occurenece by Day of Week Per Homicides File")
pylab.bar(x_values, y_values, width=bar_width, tick_label = tlabel, align = 
'center' , color = 'b')
pylab.show()

pylab.axes(aspect = 1) #used pylab example from sheet
values = [39, 11, 31, 6, 1, 2, 29, 15] #data from race/gender see above
pie_labels = ["BM", "BF", "HM", "HF", "AM", "AF", "WM", "WF"]
color_list = ['purple', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'red',
              'white']
pylab.pie(values,autopct = '%1.f%%', labels = pie_labels, colors=color_list)
pylab.title("Pie Chart Showing Racial and Gender Breakdown in Homicides File")
pylab.show()    


bar_width = .5 #used pylab examples from sheet (sets bar width)
x_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #range 0-9 (0-9,10-19,20-29... ect)
y_values = [4,7,27,41,4,15,7,6,2,5] # number of occurances per age
tlabel = ["0-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60",
          "61-70", "71-80", "81-90", "90+"]
pylab.title("Homicides per Age Categories in Homocide File")
pylab.bar(x_values, y_values, width=bar_width, tick_label = tlabel, align = 
'center' , color = 'b')
pylab.show()

bar_width = .3 #pylab example from sheet(sets bar width)
x_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
#^number of hours possible for murders
y_values = [3,3,7,1,4,6,4,4,4,5,5,3,8,4,6,2,5,13,10,6,7,5,13,6] #occurances
#of deaths per hour
tlabel = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",
          "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"]
pylab.title("Homicides Per Hour of the Clock in Homicide File")
pylab.bar(x_values, y_values, width=bar_width, tick_label = tlabel, align =
 'center' , color = 'b')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: did you try my code with your file ? I do. It removes all empty lines - even at the end of your file.

Comment: Which part @furas  im assuming the final one?

Comment: when i try the final code it errors out as `'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'`

With the first program it prints out entire document, then when going through my functions to find data it errors out as `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Date'`
Im not trying to print the lines in the document, I'm using each index per line to find a specific portion of data

Comment: try first or second (shorter) version - both do the same thing. They read all lines skiping empty one. And later you have to use list `lines` in your code

Comment: you have error `str` probably because you use `file = "C:\\..."` instead of `file = open("C:\\...")`

Comment: When trying edited I get `Days Homicides Happened on:
150101
685
Traceback (most recent call last):`
then 
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2:03'`

Comment: did you use first code instead of `file=open()`, `lines=file.readlines()` `file.close()` ?

Comment: it seems you still use `file=open(), lines=file.readlines() file.close() ` in your code - remove it.

Comment: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2:03'` this is different problem - you try to convert `int("2:30")` into number - and it has nothing to do with empty lines at the end of file.

Comment: I used the `with open () as f:
for line in f:`

Comment: My program works perfectly with the open/read statement i have above, pulls all data and makes the graphs perfectly, but it errors out when it gets to the final lines in the txt file because they are just blank spaces...

Comment: I try your "FINALE" code and it doesn't work because there are mistakes ie. you declare `dayOfmurders` and later you use `dayofmurder` with lower `O` and without `s` at the end. Check you code in question.

Comment: Thats because `dayofmurder` is a function @ top of code, and `dayOfmurders` is my dict from the txt file that consists of the name(K)S,M,T,W,Th,F,s and the number of occurances(V) 0 for all until it adds them up. theres no error in that.

Comment: sorry, now I see - your code is splitted in two parts. I took only bottom parts

Comment: Yeah i had a comment in caps showing my open/read file command, should have mentioned that, i removed it, my apologies

Comment: can you open chat? so we dont flood comments and have post flagged? I don't have enough rep to open one

Comment: I can upload the full txt file somewhere aswell if that could help you understand what my program is meant to be doing?

Comment: see in answer full example which works with your example data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered from comments you might have a couple of options, what I would do is:

## Case where it trully is just whitespace

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    headersRaw = data[0].split()
    headersFinal = [headersRaw[0],                   # Date
                    headersRaw[1]+" "+headersRaw[2], # Event #
                    headersRaw[3],                   # Time
                    headersRaw[4]+" "+headersRaw[5], # Victim name
                    headersRaw[6],                   # V
                    headersRaw[7],                   # R/G
                    headersRaw[8]+" "+headersRaw[9]  # V Age
                   ]
    i = 1
    computedData = []
    while data[i].split()[O].isdigit():
        rawData = data[i].split()
        computedData.append([rawData[0],                # Date
                             rawData[1],                # Event #
                             rawData[2],                # Time
                             rawData[3]+" "+rawData[4], # Victim name
                             rawData[5],                # V
                             rawData[6],                # R/G
                             rawData[7]                 # V Age
                            ])
        i += 1
```

So we are only going to check if the next line starts with a digit or not

## Case where next line might be something different but not whitespace

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    headersRaw = data[0].split()
    headersFinal = [headersRaw[0],                   # Date
                    headersRaw[1]+" "+headersRaw[2], # Event #
                    headersRaw[3],                   # Time
                    headersRaw[4]+" "+headersRaw[5], # Victim name
                    headersRaw[6],                   # V
                    headersRaw[7],                   # R/G
                    headersRaw[8]+" "+headersRaw[9]  # V Age
                   ]
    i = 1
    computedData = []
    while len(data[i].split()[O]) == 6:
        rawData = data[i].split()
        computedData.append([rawData[0],                # Date
                             rawData[1],                # Event #
                             rawData[2],                # Time
                             rawData[3]+" "+rawData[4], # Victim name
                             rawData[5],                # V
                             rawData[6],                # R/G
                             rawData[7]                 # V Age
                            ])
        i += 1
```

So we will check if the next data in table contains a date value of length 6

## BUT

Your data could be something different or even by error be also 6 digits long or an integer, therefore make sure that the check you do on the while loop is appropriate to the data following your table.

Its probably not the best solution, but without more info on what exactly can come afterwards its a bit difficult to come up with the perfect check in the while. I'd suggest adding something like a line of dashes or something you can easily check on to the txt file if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression with named groups. The below will parse the entire data area of your file, and do it in a way that is not arbitrary. The regular expression is a 1:1 representation of a line of data. If a line does not match it is ignored. This means you don't have to bother with skipping header lines and removing whitespace. Those aren't going to match.

```
import re
expr    = re.compile(r'^(?P<date>\d+) +(?P<event>\d+) +(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{2}) +(?P<name>[a-z]+, [a-z]+) +(?P<RG>[a-z]{2}) +(?P<age>\d{1,3}) *$', re.I)

with open("fname.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if m:=expr.match(line):
            #entry = {
            #    'date' :int(m.group('date')),
            #    'event':int(m.group('event')),
            #    'time' :m.group('time'),
            #    'name' :m.group('name'),
            #    'rg'   :m.group('RG'),
            #    'age'  :int(m.group('age')),
            #}
            ...
```

---

Here's an example of how the above could be used, based on your needs. It's an example of quite a few other things, as well.

```
import re, os, pylab
from typing import Iterable

#constants
MSTART = (0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334)
COLORS = ('purple', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'red', 'white')

DOW    = ("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
HOURS  = tuple(map(str, range(24)))
AGES   = tuple(f'{i*10}-{(i+1)*10-1}' for i in range(12)) 
RG     = ('AF','AM','BF','BM','HF','HM','WF','WM')

LABELS = (DOW, HOURS, AGES, RG)
TITLES = ('Day Of Week', 'Hour', 'Age', 'Race / Gender')

#funcs
def day(date, startonday:int=4) -> str:
    month = int(date[2:4])-1
    day   = int(date[4:])+startonday-1
    return DOW[(MSTART[month]+day)%7]
    
def prune(d:dict):
    ks, vs = [],[]
    for k,v in d.items():
        if v:
            ks.append(k)
            vs.append(v)
    return ks, vs
    
def plotter(title:str, labels:list, values:list, color:Iterable='b'):
    pylab.title(title)
    pylab.bar(range(len(labels)), values, width=.5, tick_label=labels, align='center', color=color)
    pylab.show()
    
def pie(title:str, labels:list, values:list, color:Iterable=COLORS):
    pylab.title(title)
    pylab.axes(aspect=1)
    pylab.pie(values, autopct='%1.f%%', labels=labels, colors=color)
    pylab.show()

#stats
stats = tuple({k:0 for k in targ} for targ in LABELS)

#match line
expr  = re.compile(r'^(?P<date>\d+) +(?P<event>\d+) +(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{2}) +(?P<name>[a-z]+, [a-z]+) +(?P<RG>[a-z]{2}) +(?P<age>\d{1,3})\s*$', re.I|re.M)

#update stats
with open("fname.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if m:=expr.match(line):
            d = day(m.group('date'))          #day of week
            h = m.group('time').split(':')[0] #hour
            r = m.group('RG')                 #race / gender
            
            #reformat age to key
            a = f'{m.group("age"):02}'
            a = int(a[0:len(a)-1])
            a = f'{a*10}-{(a+1)*10-1}'
                
            for targ, i in zip(stats, (d, h, a, r)):
                targ[i] += 1

#visuals
for t,l,s in zip(TITLES, LABELS, stats):
    t = f"Homicides By {t} In Homicide File"

    if l in (RG, ):
        pie(t, l, s.values())
        continue
       
    plotter(t, *prune(s))
```